# How to open camera while I click the UIButton in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uibutton

I am trying to open the camera when I click the `UIbutton` in iPhone app. I want to store the captured image in a location that I specify.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use something like this

```
- (IBAction)selectPhotos
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    imageView.image = image;
    [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)saveImage:(id)sender {
    if(imageView.image) {
        [self showProgressIndicator:@"Saving"];
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, self, @selector(finishUIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use `[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

instead of `[[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction) useCamera: (id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker
                                animated:YES];
        newMedia = YES;
    }
}
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:true];

    NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) 
    {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    imageView.image = image;
        if (newMedia)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self,  
                                           @selector(image:finishedSavingWithError:contextInfo:),nil);
    }

}
-(void)image:(UIImage *)image
finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error
 contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
    if (error) 
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                              message: @"Failed to save image"
                              delegate: self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];

    }
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```