# iphone how to go to the image gallery after taking photo through Xcode

Tags: iphone, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photo-gallery

Hi all I am implementing the following code to take a photo through my application

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] setRootViewController:picker];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:NO];
```

Can anyone tel me How I can go to the photo gallery after the user takes the photo and not return to the application.

Answer (score 2):

i think you might want to try this

[How to open camera while I click the UIButton in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929655/how-to-open-camera-while-i-click-the-uibutton-in-iphone/4929691#4929691)

or i really didn't get the question

Edit:
Well you can use the same code with `UIImagePickerControllerSourcePhotoLibrary` after taking the pic from camera. I mean call this Function with `UIImagePickerControllerSourcePhotoLibrary` then it will take you to photo Library and then back again to your application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .I am able to open the camera on click of a button. When I take the photo it gives me an option to use the photo in my application. But after clicking the photo I need to go to the photo gallery and choose a picture from the gallery and return back to my application. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImagePickerControllerSourcePhotoLibrary
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to shoot a picure use this code -

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
    [[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

If you want to go to photo gallery and wants to select a photo from there use this code -

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Notice the difference between the picker's sourceType

Comment: Thanks. I have done this now. But I need to go to the photogallery after taking a pic using my camera. Please help

Comment: I don't think its possible to open the photos application from your application. You can save the photos in your application after shooting from camera and then can use ImageBrowser module to show them check this link - https://github.com/cxan/Image-Browser

Comment: The code in this link Stores the images in the application rather than the photo gallery? Does this by any chance affect my application size or the performance?

Comment: NO it will not affect your application's setup size or performance

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is the scenario. I need to take photos and store them. Then Later upload the images to the server when internet connection is available. I have to store the image path in the database. Can you please suggest me a way. I already tried ALASSet. But It dosen seem to be a viable solution. PLease help.

Comment: you can follow this path -> 1)take photos from camera and save them in your application (document folder) 2) integrate the image browser to view photos in your app (you can also create a view controller with table view to display the photos)  3) customize the image browser or your own view to upload the photos to server.  I think its not a tuff job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I will look into the code you suggested earlier.