# iphone store image in application along with EXIF data

Tags: iphone, image, exif

This is kind of continuation of this thread

[iphone how to go to the image gallery after taking photo through Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037640/iphone-how-to-go-to-the-image-gallery-after-taking-photo-through-xcode/5062261#5062261)

I am following the method suggested by Saurabh(the link given in the comment). I just want to know if the EXIF data will be retained if I follow this method(storing the image in the application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer, yes, it will be retained.

Comment: Thank for the reply. So This means I can extraxt the latitude an longitude from the image right

Comment: Yes,but only if the image has that metadata stored in the first place along with the image data (obviously, right?).