# Creating camera view like snapchat

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a camera view like snapchat. I mean camera view will be full screen then user touches the snap button and image preview will show on screen. After that  user will touch the screen and can add a text to over of taken photo.

What is the best way to do this? Should I use `AVFoundation` or `UIImagePickerController` ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is to use UIImagePickerController. [Relevant stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929691/3287366)

Then you draw on the image received by your picker delegate.

Happy Programming!